# Terrible performance of CakePHP Tree update

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, tree, cakephp-3.0

I am using CakePHP's [Tree behavior](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/behaviors/tree.html) on a table, to map a filesystem structure.
The actual files are saved on an Amazon S3 compatible system, with the SQL table mimicking the folder structure, with a row for each "folder" in a file's key.
Through time, this table has grown to contain 700K+ rows.
When trying to add a new folder, or delete an empty one, two queries like these ones are executed:

```
UPDATE sys_files SET lft = ((lft - 2)) WHERE (lft  > 2443)
UPDATE sys_files SET rght = ((rght - 2)) WHERE (rght  > 2443)
```

Each one of these takes more than 30 second to run, causing a very unpleasant experience for the user, who is left hanging for a minute or more waiting for the operation to finish. And sometimes, the HTTP call just times out instead, which is even worse.

This happens because this these queries are updating almost every single row in the (very large) table, as these results show.

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys_files;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|   713259 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.09 sec)

mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys_files WHERE lft  > 2443;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|   704520 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.11 sec)

mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys_files WHERE rght  > 2443;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|   704546 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.11 sec)
```

I have tried adding an index on the `lft` and `rght` fields, but that didn't help because the slow part is the actual update of 700K+ lines, no the WHERE condition of the update query. But also, adding the index didn't make performance noticeably worse, so I'm not that concerned by either keeping it or leaving it... the problem is the update itself, with or without the index.

Comment: "Left-right" design is cute, but not efficient.

Comment: In particular, `UPDATEing` 700K rows of _any_ table will be slow.  Adding an index will make it slower because of the need to update the Index as well as the Data.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried adding an index on the `lft` and `rght` fields, but that didn't help because the slow part is the actual update of 700K+ lines, no the WHERE condition of the update query.

What's probably happening is that the index has to re-create itself after you update the columns `lft` or `rght`.

What we could try is to use the indexes on a copy table (sf_copy), so they are not going to be re-created on each `UPDATE` by MySQL.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE sf_copy LIKE sys_files;
INSERT INTO sf_copy SELECT * FROM sys_files;
```

Then re-create indexes on `sys_files_copy` table (columns `lft` and `rght`).

Then try the following :

```
UPDATE   sys_files AS sf, 
         sf_copy AS sc 
SET      sf.lft = sf.lft - 2
WHERE    sc.lft  > 2443 
         AND sc.id = sf.id;
```

(Please note the `sc.id = sf.id` part. It's is important to make the JOIN)

Comment: I think having to juggle two tables instead of one creates more problems than it solves... first of all, the update queries are fired by Cake's internal code, so I would have to jump through a lot of hoops to change that as I cannot simply edit the code.
Secondly, I would have to implement similar changes for every CRUD operation, not only the deletion, to keep the two tables in sync.
Lastly, this means that searches on the sys_files table that involve the lft and rght fields would have to be joined with the additional table, because that's where the indexes for those fields reside.

Answer (score 0):

(This may not be possible to implement because of the 3rd party package wanting to be in control.)

```
UPDATE sys_files SET lft = ((lft - 2)) WHERE (lft  > 2443)
UPDATE sys_files SET rght = ((rght - 2)) WHERE (rght  > 2443)
```

-->

```
CREATE TABLE tmp
    SELECT ((other columns)),
           IF (lft  > 2443, lft  - 2, lft )  AS lft,
           IF (rght > 2443, rght - 2, rght)  AS rght,
           ((other columns))
    FROM sys_files;
ALTER TABLE tmp ADD ((whatever indexes you had));
RENAME sys_files TO old,
       tmp TO sys_files;
DROP TABLE old;
```

That might run noticeably faster for a 700K-row table, but not very fast for a 10-row table, nor if `2443` is near the 'end' of the table.